# Script Message Box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have the following function:

```
  Public Function javaMsg(ByVal message As String) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

that's how i'm calling my function:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", x.javaMsg("Do you want to choose a date?"), True)
```

this alert only shows an ok button how can i add a cancel button? and how can i use every button on click to do a certain job?

note that i'm using asp.net with vb.net

Comment: use confirm box in place of alert box.

Comment: @SainPradeep okey now how can i write a function if the user chose ok and another function if the user chose cancel?

Comment: @SainPradeep i mean from code behind of course

Comment: this isn't a good way to unaccept an answer that was previously accepted. you should have asked question properly.... for future guidance plz refer to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the jQuery UI dialog. It is the most common dialog used right now.

Check the following link:

[Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Here you have an example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `confirm` instead of `alert`...

```
  Public Function javaMsg(ByVal message As String) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("var r=confirm('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("');");
        sb.Append("if(r==true){");
        sb.Append("alert('clicked OK');}");
        sb.Append("else{");
        sb.Append("alert('clicked CANCEL');}");
        sb.Append("};");

        return sb.ToString();

End Function
```

Comment: okey now how can i write a function if the user chose ok and another function if the user chose cancel?

Comment: i need to get the result of the confirm box in the code behind in vb.. not is the javascript..

Comment: i guess stackoverlfow is the forum to help you in programming, not to code on your behalf. you can find lots of examples over internet. if you are unable to figure out how to do so, please create new thread. as this thread is officially off as you have got answer whatever you wanted to ask. Thanks

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury btw you can set hidden field from javascript confirm box  with true and false. and access that hidden field in code behind. PEACE B-)